# If I deny location permissions on Chrome and allow them again, the changed location permissions will not apply properly

Tags: google-chrome, next.js, geolocation, location, next.js13

i am using Next.js 13 and This problem occurred in the localhost development environment through yarn dev.

I'm trying to use geolocation. When asked for location permission in Chrome for the first time, if you allow it, geolocation works without any problems. However, if you reject it and allow it again, it doesn't work properly. Chrome allowed it, so of course it should be allowed on the web app, but it feels like Chrome and the web app are playing separately. How on earth can we solve this problem?

1. Of course, I've tried refreshing it, but the location permission is still denied.
2. I thought it was a cache issue, so I tried a strong refresh of Chrome (clearing the cache), but the location permissions are still denied.
3. I manually deleted it because I thought it was a problem with local storage or session storage, but location permissions are still denied.